# How can I compile solidity contract with multiple files from source codes from Etherscan API?

Tags: solidity, etherscan

response of API are below

```
{
   "status":"1",
   "message":"OK",
   "result":[
      {
         "SourceCode":"",
         "ABI":"",
         "ContractName": "",
         "ConstructorArguments": "",
         "EVMVersion":"Default",
         "Library":"",
         "LicenseType":"",
         "Proxy":"0",
         "Implementation":"",
         "SwarmSource":""
      }
   ]
}
```

the "SourceCode" is string, and multiple files will be merge in this field, can I use solc compile this merged SourceCode to get bytecode of the contract? and How? Or must I split the source code into correspond files according the directory architecture?